# JQuery Mobile and Submit Ajax Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

I added Jquery mobile and it's working fine in my html pages but Now I want to submit an ajax form then How can I do this?

If I submit ajax form then it will take html request and getting error : Missing Partial

Is there any way to submit a ajax form in jquery mobile?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Submit a **ajax** form in **jquery mobile**

```
var form_data = $('#form_id').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://example.com',
    data: form_data,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(){
        //functions to be executed before sending AJAX request
    },
    complete: function(){
        //functions to be executed after completing AJAX requests
    },
    success: function(data){
         //functions to be executed if AJAX request is successful
    },
   error: function(){
        // get error
   }
})
```

Comment: Not Working - still going to html request, Anything need to change on submit button ?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile has its own way of form handling which need to taken into account.

First you must add data-ajax="false" attribute to your form, like this:

```
<form data-ajax="false" method="post" action="second.php">
```

It will force jQuery Mobile to use classic form handling. Next thing you need to do, if you are submitting the form, is prevent this process with **return false;** or **event.preventDefault();**

Then submit AJAX call, when you receive response, if it is a successful response, then programmatically change and show needed page.

Everything would look something like this:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#login', function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { // catch the form's submit event
        if($('#username').val().length > 0 && $('#password').val().length > 0){
            // Send data to server through the ajax call
            // action is functionality we want to call and outputJSON is our data
                $.ajax({url: 'check.php',
                    data: {action : 'login', formData : $('#check-user').serialize()},
                    type: 'post',                  
                    async: 'true',
                                            dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
                        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); // This will show ajax spinner
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
                        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // This will hide ajax spinner
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        if(result.status) {
                            $.mobile.changePage("#second");                        
                        } else {
                            alert('Logon unsuccessful!');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (request,error) {
                        // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action               
                        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                    }
                });                  
        } else {
            alert('Please fill all necessary fields');
        }          
        return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
    });   
});
```

Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-correctly-submit-form-data-in-jquery-mobile/)**.

And don't forget, if your AJAX service is on some other domain, you will need to do a cross-domain call with **JSONP** instead of **JSON**.